# modal from dropdown menu item

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to do a modal from a drop-down menu item in bootstrap beta 4.0. It doesn't seem to be working.  I've used the same format on other modals on the page and they are working.

```
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#insurance-head-section" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Insurance</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-item">New Patient</a>
          <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Established Patient</a>
          <a href="#response"
          class="dropdown-item"
          data-toggle="modal" data-target="response">Responsibilities</a>
          <a href="" class="dropdown-item">link 4</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

The modal is below:

```
  <div class="modal" id="response">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
      <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="list-group">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
          <h6>Responsibilities</h6>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a hash before your `data-target`

```
<a href="#response" class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#response">Responsibilities</a>
```

You'll see that is required in their documentation here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modal-components

And here is a link to a codepen where it is working:

https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/jGzjOz

Comment: Thank you, I had been staring at that for hours.  I had done it everywhere else just missed it here.